# How to describe someone who doesn't listen well

Tags: adjectives, expressions

How would you describe someone who doesn't listen well? I don't mean someone who has hearing problems. I mean someone who doesn't finish listening and starts interrupting the conversation.

Comment: @Jeff Atwood - Why was this closed as not constructive?

Comment: @man see the [faq] particularly the section about "can probably be easily answered by looking it up". Question demonstrates no research, and is very broad.

Comment: @JeffAtwood - Gotcha. But weird that StackEnglish (twitter) has been tweeting about this and StackExchange retweeting it :D

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Depending on the exact reason for the listener doing this, you might say that he is *[impulsive](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/impulsive)*, if he is interrupting because it is the first thing that comes into his head, or that he is *[impatient](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/impatient)*, because he can't wait to put his ha'pence worth in, or he might be *[intolerant](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/intolerant)*, if he wants to suppress or pre-empt any possibility of a dissenting (or concurring) opinion.

Answer (score 8):

I would call them **bad listener**.

Comment: Of course, we could have just left OP with his original *person who doesn't listen well*, but you're right - *bad listener* is effectively a set phrase.

Answer (score 4):

Without assigning motivation to the act as @Brian Hooper's options do, I'd suggest *boorish*, *uncouth*,  or simply *rude*.